# Access server xsp.properties value in osgi servlet

Tags: xpages

I am building an application that will run solely on the Domino Server. It will not be bound specifically to any application and there is no designer library associated with it. I still need to access configuration values in order to get it to run correctly.

My first thought is to use the server xsp.properties file. Because this does not exist at first I will copy the sample and put my own properties into it. How can I access those values when I am only using the OSGi servlet?

I do have an ODA (openNTF Domino API) dependency, albeit an older version from September 2014.

Comment: xsp.properties are imho bound to a database. If you are looking for a place for static values, add a method to your activator and let it read either a resource (if the value is determined at bundle packaging time or notes.ini. If it is a lot: provide a config database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OpenNTF Domino API, you can use `ODAPlatform.getXspPropertyAsString()`. This goes through `Platform.getProperty()` (I believe this one uses xsp.properties of the application / server), `System.getProperty()`, then OS.OSGetEnvironmentString() (i.e. notes.ini). This is what the OpenLog functionality uses, as does a lot of code for getting `org.openntf.domino` xsp.property settings.

Alternative, you can have a look at the XPages OpenLog Logger code, which is where I originally wrote the code. The `com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogUtil` class has a `getXspProperty(String, String)` method, which uses `com.ibm.xsp.application.ApplicationEx.getInstance().getApplicationProperty(String propertyName, String defaultValue))`.

Comment: For some reason, ApplicationEx is null. (I tried to 'borrow' the code from openLog before. It also seems like the XPages SDK Plugin is not taking the new plugins after I updated ODA.  (I was using a version from 2014. It seemed as though org.openntf.domino.xsp.ODAPlatform was not in the API at that time). Eclipse cannot find the class yet. I am installing the plugins onto the domino server via an update site, and I am not pasting them onto the server directly.

Comment: Try adding the ODA plugins to the Target Platform in Eclipse. That should allow Eclipse to see them. In XPages OpenLog Logger, I'm also adding com.ibm.xsp.designer as a Required Plug-in and com.ibm.xsp.application as an Imported Package (though it may not need adding as an Imported Package as well, I'm not sure).

Comment: In the end, going with the server notes.ini was the way to go. The main thing was to use a good old fashioned lotus.domino.Session fetched through the NotesFactory.createTrustedSession, then use getEnvironmentString("whatever", true)